# Moxy и ViewBinding

Tags: android, moxy

Как совместить Moxy и ViewBinding? Начинаю изучать Moxy и возникает проблема, что onFirstViewAttach Срабатывает раньше, чем я успеваю привязать layout. Как решить эту проблему?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), MainView {

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun displayTextView(text: String) {
        binding.textView.text = text
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MainPresenter : MvpPresenter<MainView>() {
    override fun onFirstViewAttach() {
        viewState.displayTextView("УРА")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использовал не тот callback onCreate. Правильный - `onCreate(savedInstanseState: Bundle?)`